# How to get a value from an array using ID name in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am getting value form API `graduated` and I want to print original text from below array.

**API Response**

[image]

**Current Result as below image**

[image]

**.ts file**

```
 levelEducation = [
    {id: "not-graduated", name: "OTHERS.NotGraduated"},
    {id: "graduated", name: "OTHERS.Graduation"},
    {id: "master", name: "OTHERS.Master"},
    {id: "doctorate", name: "OTHERS.Doctorate"},
  ];
```

**HTML file code**

```
 <div class="form-field">
     <label>{{'JOBAPPLICATION.LevelOfEducation' | translate}}</label>
     <h5>{{userData.livello_studi ? userData.livello_studi : '-'}}</h5>
     <h5 *ngFor="let item of levelEducation">{{(item.name ? item.name : '-' ) | translate}}</h5>
 </div>
```

So I need to value "OTHERS.Graduation" using ID name `graduated` in angular.

Comment: I don't really know what the expected behaviour is. Do you want to map gradated to Graduation? You could do this with a hardcoded mapping. Not quite sure what "OTHER." should do. I am a little puzzeld here. Maybe you have some clearification :)

Comment: "OTHER." is used for multi languages so for now consider as a simple text.

Comment: Is the question more about how to translate different texts in your frontend? Like you have a french frontend, a polish etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to use a map between `livello_studi` value and the display value that you want.

I guess `OTHERS` is an enum, so first you'll need to define the map data.

```js
levelEducation = new Map([
  ["not-graduated", OTHERS.NotGraduated],
  ["graduated", OTHERS.Graduation],
  ["master", OTHERS.Master],
  ["doctorate", OTHERS.Doctorate],
]);
```

To get data from the map you do it like this

```js
levelEducation.get(userData.livello_studi); // this will return undefined if the item is not found
```

So you could do this in the template to get the data:

```html
<h5>{{levelEducation.get(userData.livello_studi) || '-'}}</h5>
```

(or move this code into a function for cleanliness)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map the values from graduated to Graduation you can solve this with a map.
Assumed you have n values and this is not an editable input.

```
let map = new Map();
map.set("graduated" ","Graduation");
map.set("not-graduated","Not graduated");
```

....

and later when you need to display your value you can write a function which displays your displayabletext when you need it.

```
return map.get("graduated");
```